# tensorflow: How to access and reuse feature column values?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow's wide & deep model tutorial, it constructed some feature columns like:

```
wide_columns = [gender, native_country, education, occupation, workclass,
              relationship, age_buckets,
              tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column([education, occupation],
                                               hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)),
              tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column(
                  [age_buckets, education, occupation],
                  hash_bucket_size=int(1e6)),
              tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column([native_country, occupation],
                                               hash_bucket_size=int(1e4))]
```

I want to directly reuse his columns result/values to construct my wide & deep model with another deep learning library, but how can I access these values after feed inputs ? or how to save into file ? I didn't found any method that export true data, so I need help.